# vlc player unable to play m3u8 play list

Tags: ubuntu, vlc, m3u, m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-1.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-2.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-3.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-4.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-5.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-6.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-7.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-8.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-9.ogg
#EXTINF: 10
wr3libvorbis-10.ogg
#EXTINF: 9
wr3libvorbis-11.ogg
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

this is my m3u8 file placed in the folder containing all the videos in the list. vlc plays each video in the list perfectly, so there is no problem with videos in the list. But vlc stays dumb when its is fed with this m3u8 file. Is there any problem with the list? please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you are missing these 2 tags at the beginning:

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
```

Besides that, VLC seem to buggy when play m3u8 file. In my case, I couldn't get it run using double click on m3u8 file. I have to open VLC first, use Ctrl + O and choose the m3u8 file. I recommend you use `ffplay` or another player likes `JWPlayer` ,`Viblast` .